# Json deserialization for java object

Tags: java, json, deserialization

I have a class that contains java object, it contains other classes ignoring for now

```
class A {
   B b;
}

class B {        
    String name;
    Object value; // value can be a string, list or int

    //setters, getters for name

    public void setValue(Object value) {this.value = value;}
    public Object getValue() { return this.value;}
}
```

I am taking input as json to my api using jaxr, like this:

```
 @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 public Response getData(A a) throws JsonProcessingException {
     A.getB().getValue();
 }
```

The problem is `getValue()` always returns as `ElementNSImpl` object, I want to return as Java Object so that I can check the instance and create objects accordingly.

This is how Json input look like:

```
{    
    b: {
      "name": "product",
       "value": "thisIsString"  // than I want to create string class. 
          or 
       "value": ["item1", "item2"] // list class
          or
       "value": 232 // int class
}
```

Comment: There are multiple framework to doing that, one of them is google [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) and you can simply accomplish that through this code: Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
Address address=gson.fromJson(json, Address.class);

Comment: Can I do without that ? getData gets called directly through jersey and serializes the json object automatically. If I have to do above way than I would read the data first and than serializes it.